# How can I get my Node server to respond to POST requests on multiple paths?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, express, nodemailer

I get 404 errors on only one path, but success emails with 500 errors responses on the other.

I have two paths that for handling emails for different forms on the same website. Only `/send` works but the second one always fails unless I also change its path to `/send`. I am using Nodemailer.

Can Express only handle one POST path per server?

I'll assume something related to this is the problem.

```
/** * Production Settings */
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    // changes it to use the optimized version for production
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}
module.exports = app;
```

Email related code:

```
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var ses = require('nodemailer-ses-transport');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
var tableify = require('tableify');
//var routes = require('./routes/index');
//var users = require('./routes/users');
//var mailer = require('express-mailer');
//var mailer = require('./send');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(ses({
    accessKeyId: '****',
    secretAccessKey: '******',
    ServiceUrl: 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
}));

/*Contact form mailer*/
app.post('/contactform', function(req, res, next) {
    var sendit = {
        to: '****@gmail.com',
        from: '*****@****nightphoto.com',
        replyTo: req.body.email,
        subject: '*************m' + req.body.name + ' ' + req.body.phone,
        text: req.body.message + '\n' + '\n' + 'Customer Name address: ' + req.body.fname + '\n' + 'Customer email address: ' + req.body.email + '\n' + 'Customer Phone Number: ' + req.body.phone + '\n' + 'Reason:' + req.body.reason,
    };
    transporter.sendMail(sendit, function(req, res, err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err + "something strange...");
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send("It's ok!");
            console.log("Message sent! ");
        }
        transporter.close();
    })
    res.send(status);
});

//Second path - this works just fine because it's using send.
app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
    var cartContent = req.body.slice(1, 20);
    var content = tableify(cartContent);
    var sendit = {
        to: '***@gmail.com',
        from: '*****l@****nightphoto.com ',
        replyTo: req.body[0].email,
        subject: "*****: " + req.body[0].fname + " " + req.body[0].lname,
        html: '<b>Customer Quote</b>' + '<br>' + 'Customer Name: ' + req.body[0].fname + " " + req.body[0].lname + '<br>' + 'Customer E-mail address: ' + req.body[0].email + '<br>' + 'Customer Phone Number: ' + req.body[0].phone + '<br>' + "Street Address: " + req.body[0].street + "," + req.body[0].state + ',' + req.body[0].zipCode + '<br>' + '<b>Total Price: $</b>' + req.body[0].totalQuote + '<br>' + '<b>Table</b>' + '<br><br>' + content,
    };
    transporter.sendMail(sendit, function(req, res, data, config, status, err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err + "something strange..." + data);
        } else {
            console.log(content);
            console.log("Message sent! ");
        }
        transporter.close();
    });
    res.send(status);
});
```

Comment: Really hard  to understand from the code you have given,  can you please provide with the error message for 500 code? (from node console)

Comment: There's really not enough to go on here. Please include more of the route code, include the code that is trying to hit these routes, etc.

Comment: I included the complete app.js code. Node.js returns a 500 internal service error but my nodemailer reports success, message sent. The path /contact form doesn't work at all unless I change it to /send.

Comment: How about client-side code? Does your `form` actually has `action="/contactform"`?

Comment: I have an angular controller for that activated by NG-Click

Comment: What does its code look like? Does it actually call your `POST /contactform` route? Sidenote: [You have to @mention someone for them to get notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: @laggingreflex yes, but returns a 404 error, no page found and no processing occured.

Comment: You haven't included the code how your client actually calls the `POST /contactform` route